# How to use PFCloud callFunction Xcode 7

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cloud, swift2, xcode7

```
let params = NSMutableDictionary()
params.setObject(fullName.text!.lowercaseString, forKey: "username")

let result: AnyObject? = PFCloud.callFunction("checkUsername", withParameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

This worked in Xcode 6.3, but now that I update to Swift 2 (Xcode 7) it no longer works. I get the error message:

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

How can I resolve this?

Also, I don't want to use `PFCloud.callFunctionBackground`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let params = NSMutableDictionary()
params.setObject(fullName.text!.lowercaseString, forKey: "username")

let result: AnyObject? = try! PFCloud.callFunction("checkUsername", withParameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

In Swift 2.0 try-catch syntax was added, you can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Comment: it works, however, I still don't quite understand (I know what try-catch is but why does try! work). Would you mind just giving me a quick explanation?

Comment: @nick9999 `try!` can be used if you're sure that exception will never throw. If some error is possible, it's better to add catch block.